# TextView vertical center

Tags: android, textview

Andriod text view vertical center problem

[image: View Screenshot]

**My Code**

```
<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:fontFamily="@font/googlesansbold"
       android:text="Tance"
       android:lineHeight="1dp"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every font has extra padding. You can`t easily remove that padding.

You can to write own textView that extend AppCompatTextView and override onDraw.
The simplest way is to use that [textView](https://github.com/SenhLinsh/NoPaddingTextView).

Using:

You need to hard code attribute android:height="dp" on your own preference

```
<NoPaddingTextView
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:background="#c1c1c1"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:lineHeight="1dp"
    android:text="Tance"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Try using

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: You need to post your code for xml file. so we can have some idea. Kindly post xml file code.

Comment: here is xml file   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V2HBf-pz093xQfVu4HKCiqzfbXp971FR

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent layout is a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation 
and the size of the `TextView` is `wrap_content`, 
use this attribute for the **parent** layout and **not** for the `TextView`:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: here is xml file drive.google.com/open?id=1V2HBf-pz093xQfVu4HKCiqzfbXp971FR

Comment: @Thomas I saw the layout and with this attribute the TextView **is** centered

Comment: @Thomas you don't need `android:gravity="center_vertical"` inside the TextView, only in the LinearLayout

Comment: @Thomas not `android:gravity="center|center_vertical"`, only `android:gravity="center_vertical"`